# How to disable session restore message in vscode terminal

Tags: visual-studio-code, terminal

[image]

I don't want this message appearing **session contents restored** every time I open terminal. Why can't it restore and just doesn't show any msg or at least provide a option to do it.

Comment: I don't see a way to disable the message but keep the terminal restore functionality.

Comment: @Mark Yes true.

Answer (score 60):

This feature can be disabled using the following two lines. Open "**settings**" -> Enter these commands to revert the VSCode behavior. Set them to **never and false**.

```
"terminal.integrated.persistentSessionReviveProcess": "never",
"terminal.integrated.enablePersistentSessions": false
```

[image]

Comment: I just don't want message i want keep the functionality

Comment: One may also want to experiment with `terminal.integrated.persistentSessionScrollback`

Answer (score 4):

since there's currently no way to disable the message but keeping the functionality, executing `clear` command on the terminal startup is my current workaround.

for powershell, just add `clear` command to the profile.

Answer (score 0):

VSCode 1.69 (June 2022) should remove that message in some instances:

See [PR 152408 "Restore old buffers if no additional interactions happened"](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/pull/152408) from [issue 142855](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/142855)

> This makes terminals only restore their current session's buffer if there was some interaction by the user, similar to how the initial process doesn't get revived if no interaction occurred.

That would allow to pass from:

[image: https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/2193314/154096613-721e477b-c3c0-4fcc-9c11-75c8f460678b.png]

To:

```bash
Tyriar\xterm.js  master [?]
❯

 Session contents restored from 2/15/2022 at 7:39:34 AM 

Shell integration activated!

Tyriar\xterm.js  master [?] 
❯
```

Slightly less "loud".