# Vs Code uses old R version in terminal when opened inside of folder

Tags: r, visual-studio-code

I just upgraded R from 4.2.2 -> 4.3.2.

[Using this question on here,](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72707869/changing-r-version-in-vs-code) I told VSCode where to find the new R version, and for the most part it works great.

If I have no folders open, and start a new R terminal, it opens 4.3.2.  Great!

Problem is, if I go open a folder I've previously had open with R files in it, it'll boot up a terminal for 4.2.2.  How do I tell it to use the most recent version globally?

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out.  I had persistent sessions enabled and it was reloading the history.  Fixed it with this: [How to disable session restore message in vscode terminal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70285159/how-to-disable-session-restore-message-in-vscode-terminal)